# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) in "print >> ..." statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, python-2.x, python-3.6

When I try to run this code under Python 3.6:

```
import sys

print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
```

I get this `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Chanhc1997/Desktop/test_c.py", line 8, in <module>
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>:
'builtin_function_or_method' and 'PseudoOutputFile'.
Did you mean "print(<message>, file=<output_stream>)"?
```

The code works fine in Python 2. What's going on?

Comment: The answer to your question is included in the error message: instead of `print >>sys.stderr, TEXT` you must use `print (TEXT, file=sys.stderr)` when using Python 3.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I wonder that why the same code can work on openwrt( linkit 7688 duo, python supported) while on python-3.6 compiler we need to modify the print() part before compiling??

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2, this:

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
```

means "print the string `'waiting for a connection'` to the file-like object `sys.stderr`".

In Python 3, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) becomes a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) rather than a statement, and the syntax to redirect its output looks like this:

```
print('waiting for a connection', file=sys.stderr)
```

You get a `TypeError` (rather than, say, a `SyntaxError`) in Python 3 because, now that `print` is a function (and therefore an object), it can be part of an expression … and since `>>` is an operator, the expression fragment

```
print >>sys.stderr
```

is interpreted as "[shift](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) the `print` function right by `sys.stderr` bits" – which is syntactically valid, but doesn't make any sense for those objects.

If you need to write code which runs under both Python 2 and Python 3, you can import Python 3's behaviour into Python 2:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # works in Python 2.6 and onwards

print('whatever', file=some_file)
```

Note that this will disable the ability to treat `print` as a statement, so you'll have to update any code which uses that behaviour.